# Swift crash Crashlytics 0x0000000104fbdf84

Tags: ios, swift

Crashlytics showed that my app crashed on the line 238, actually this issue happened for quite some time. I tried to simulate this issue on simulator and test phone, but no crash happened.

I tried adding validations on the phoneNo variable and change the function used to change the label text. But the crash still happening.

Crashlytics

[Crashlytics issue details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTuGf.png)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        verifyCodeTF.textContentType = .oneTimeCode
    } 
    hideKeyboard()

    eventLogger(eventKey: FirebaseKeyConstructor.getPhoneNumberVerificationKey(), eventType: viewOpenedEvent)
    phoneValidation()

    print(labelPhoneNo)
    if let phoneNo = labelPhoneNo {
/*line 238 here*/resendLabel.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat(LocalizedString.getResentLabelStr(), phoneNo) 
        //resendLabel.text = String(format: LocalizedString.getResentLabelStr(), phoneNo)
    }
    resend()
    addDefaultBackground()

}
```

Phone validation function as below :

```
func phoneValidation() {
    let country = defaults.string(forKey: countryKey)
    let phoneNo = defaults.string(forKey: userPhoneKey)
    if country != nil && phoneNo != nil {
        switch country {
        case malaysiaCountry:
            if (phoneNo?.hasPrefix("0"))! {
                formattedPhoneNo = "+6" + phoneNo!
            } else if (phoneNo?.hasPrefix("1"))! {
                formattedPhoneNo = "+60" + phoneNo!
            } else if (phoneNo?.hasPrefix("6"))! {
                formattedPhoneNo = "+" + phoneNo!
            } else {
                formattedPhoneNo = phoneNo
            }
        case singaporeCountry:
            if (phoneNo?.hasPrefix("65"))! {
                formattedPhoneNo = "+" + phoneNo!
            } else if phoneNo?.hasPrefix("+65") == false {
                formattedPhoneNo = "+65" + phoneNo!
            } else {
                formattedPhoneNo = phoneNo
            }
        case indonesiaCountry:
            if (phoneNo?.hasPrefix("62"))! {
                formattedPhoneNo = "+" + phoneNo!
            } else if phoneNo?.hasPrefix("+62") == false {
                formattedPhoneNo = "+62" + phoneNo!
            } else {
                formattedPhoneNo = phoneNo
            }
        case thailandCountry:
            if (phoneNo?.hasPrefix("66"))! {
                formattedPhoneNo = "+" + phoneNo!
            } else if phoneNo?.hasPrefix("+66") == false {
                formattedPhoneNo = "+66" + phoneNo!
            } else {
                formattedPhoneNo = phoneNo
            }
        default:
            formattedPhoneNo = phoneNo
        }
        labelPhoneNo = formattedPhoneNo
        labelPhoneNo.insert(" ", at: labelPhoneNo.index(labelPhoneNo.startIndex, offsetBy: 3))
    } else {
        performStopAlert(title: AlertMessages.getErrorMsg(), message: "Country or phone number is empty, please try again...")
    }

}
```

LocalizedString.getResentLabelStr() value:

```
static private let resendLabel      : String = NSLocalizedString("Resend_Label", comment: "")

static func getResentLabelStr() -> String {
    return resendLabel
}
```

LocalizedString for English, Thai (Indonesia is using English locale as well)

```
English : "Resend_Label" = "Your SMS code will arrive in 2 minutes to phone number %@. If you have not received it, please click on the Resend button below."
Thai : "Resend_Label" = "คุณจะได้รับรหัส SMS ภายใน 2 นาที ไปยังหมายเลขโทรศัพท์ %@. หากยังไม่ได้รับกรุณาคลิกที่ปุ่มด้านล่างอีกครั้ง";
```

Comment: Which line is 238? Very hard to understand what could have caused a crash without knowing the functions being called in this scope.

Comment: resendLabel.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat(LocalizedString.getResentLabelStr(), phoneNo)
What is `LocalizedString.getResentLabelStr()`? What's the locale when it fails? Is the phone number valid?

Comment: @andromedainiative the line 238 is resendLabel.text = String.localizedStringWithFormat(LocalizedString.getResentLabelStr(), phoneNo). I will add the phone validation function in the post also.

Comment: @Larme Sorry, didn't track on the locale that it crashed, the app currently using English, Indonesia, and Thai language. Previously tested using valid Malaysia, Thailand and Indonesia phone number, there is no crashes, thus still thinking what is the causes of the crash. I will add the localizedString in the post.

Comment: What's the value of `LocalizedString.getResentLabelStr()`? I'm wondering if it's calling a string with a bad placeholder.

Comment: @Larme I updated the post again, u can find the value of LocalizedString.getResentLabelStr() above.